# Irrationality measure of the number is itself

Tags: nt.number-theory, diophantine-approximation

Does there exist real number $\theta\in \mathbb{R}$\ $\mathbb{Q}$ such that [Irrationality Measure](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/IrrationalityMeasure.html) of  $\theta$ is itself?

$$\forall \epsilon >0, \exists C>0, \forall(p,q)\in \mathbb{Z^2},\bigg|\theta-\frac{p}{q} \bigg|\geq\frac{C}{q^{\theta+\epsilon}}$$

Comment: What is written by the formula is "the measure of irrationality of the number is at least itself", yes?

Comment: Looks like $3+\sum_n q_n^{-1}$ where $q_1=2$, $q_n|q_{n+1}$ and $q_{n+1}\approx q_n^{3+\sum_{k\le n}q_k^{-1}}$ does the job, doesn't it?

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/91210/is-there-any-real-number-except-1-which-is-equal-to-its-own-irrationality-measur